# IdentityServer4 API Use of Bearer Access Token Redirects to Login

Tags: identityserver4, abp

I am using [ABP Commercial](https://commercial.abp.io/) which comes with Identity Server 4, and I am having trouble allowing access to an API Endpoint.

I have used ABP to configure a Client which has an API Resource, and I am able to successfully request a Bearer access token, and it contains the scope I expect.

The problem is that I can't seem to use the Bearer token to gain access to my API endpoint. What happens is my request is redirected to the default login page and the API endpoint is not hit.

I have tried many different things including decorating the API endpoint method with the `[Authorize]` tag.

Part of the problem is ABP abstracts away some of the Identity Server stuff and so the default tutorial ([reference](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html)) does not seem to apply completely.

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler? I would recommend using it to drill down into exactly where the error occur. your question is a bit to wage to be able to give any sensible answers. Does your API actually get the request with the token? is the token valid? how is the token included in the request? (in the authorization header?) Can you see something in the logs from the API?

Comment: @ToreNestenius yes, I understand (it is difficult to explain). In Postman I see an HTML response which corresponds to the Login Page of the ASP.NET Core application (were you to browse to the page). I believe the request to the API endpoint is simply redirecting to the login page. The API method doesn't even get hit as I believe Identity Server is intercepting the request. The Audit Logs show nothing. The token is included in the request using a Bearer Token Authorization header.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment out the authorize headers or create an endpoint without authorization. Then in it put a breakpoint, to see if the ClaimsPrincial (The User) object is populated as expected.

Or use some code like this one to dump out the content of the user to the HTTP response or to the log.

```
private void DumpUser(HttpContext context)
{
    ClaimsPrincipal user = context.User;

    context.Response.WriteAsync("<h3>Identities</h3>");
    foreach (ClaimsIdentity identity in user.Identities)
    {

        context.Response.WriteAsync($"<h4>identity</h4>");
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"Name: {user.Identity.Name ?? "null"}<br>");
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"Is Authenticated: {user.Identity.IsAuthenticated}<br>");
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"AuthenticationType: {user.Identity.AuthenticationType ?? "null"}<br>");
    }

    context.Response.WriteAsync("<h3>Claims</h3>");
    context.Response.WriteAsync(@"<table>");
    context.Response.WriteAsync(@"<thead><tr><th>Type</th><th>Value</th><th>Issuer</th></tr></thead>");
    foreach (Claim claim in user.Claims)
    {
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"<tr>");
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"<td>{claim.Type}</td>");
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"<td>{claim.Value}</td>");
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"<td>{claim.Issuer}</td>");
        context.Response.WriteAsync($"</tr>");
    }
    context.Response.WriteAsync($"</table>");
}
```

then you can easily call this method from within the startup.Configure method:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<!DOCTYPE html><body>");

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");

    DumpUser(context);
});
```

You need to first isolate where the problem is, is it authentication? or authorization? Does the API get the token and can it create a valid authenticated user object based on the incoming token?

Comment: Thanks a huge amount but I just couldn't get any of it to work, so I have decided to go with simple API Key authentication for now.